# MySql stored functions: Not works

Tags: mysql

I have the following function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS saveTableRow;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION saveTableRow(adapter_id int(10), view_id int(10),name varchar(255)) RETURNS TINYINT(1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE retOK TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tables` WHERE `adapter_id`=adapter_id AND `view_id`=view_id AND `name`=name ) = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `tables` (`adapter_id`,`view_id`,`name`) VALUES (adapter_id, view_id, name);
        SET retOK = 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN retOK;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i call the function to insert a new row with

```
SELECT saveTableRow(3,1,'Text');
```

I get the result '0' and there is no new row saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a name collision problem. The name of the column is the same with the name of you parameter. You need to change the name of your parameter that is different from the name of your column. eg,

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS saveTableRow;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION saveTableRow(
       _adapter_id int(10), 
       _view_id int(10),
       _name varchar(255)) 
RETURNS TINYINT(1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE retOK TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `tables` 
         WHERE `adapter_id`=_adapter_id AND 
               `view_id`=_view_id AND
               `name`=_name ) = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `tables` (`adapter_id`,`view_id`,`name`) 
        VALUES (_adapter_id, _view_id, _name);
        SET retOK = 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN retOK;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: instead of `SET retOK = 1;` try, `SET retOK = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: In this case shouldn't use `START TRANSACTION ` ?

Answer (score 0):

change the if as follows as try please:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tables` WHERE `adapter_id`=adapter_id AND `view_id`=view_id AND `name`=name ) < 1)
```